# how do I order rows, then group them, then order groups

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a user inbox for private messages where it shows the *one* most recent message between two people, and the orders all conversations by most recent as well. It should perform just like Facebook messages inbox, where you click a preview of the most recent message to see the full conversation, and conversations are ordered by most recent too. This is the statement I have so far, but it's not showing anything and I can't figure out how to fix it. Does anybody have any advice?

```
$sqlInbox = "
    SELECT sender, receiver, message, parent, rView
    FROM (SELECT sender, receiver, message, parent, rView
        FROM messages 
        WHERE receiver='$log_username' OR sender='$log_username'
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
    GROUP BY parent
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
```

The parent column represents the full conversation, so any messages between two set people, regardless of who sent or received, will have the same parent ID in the table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it getting an error? Are you checking for errors?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that you need to group by all the columns you are selecting.

```
SELECT sender, receiver, message, parent, rView
FROM (SELECT sender, receiver, message, parent, rView
    FROM messages 
    WHERE receiver='$log_username' OR sender='$log_username'
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
GROUP BY sender, receiver, message, parent, rView
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't require this.

Comment: And if you group by all columns, there's no point in grouping, you can just use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I was thinking of using distinct instead of group by. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works..

```
SELECT sender, receiver, message, parent, rView
FROM messages 
WHERE receiver='$log_username' OR sender='$log_username'
ORDER BY parent ASC, timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Still the same issue. Conversations are ordered by most recent message, but each conversation is still displaying the first-ever message, not the most recent one.

Comment: Your question says you're not getting _any_ output, not that you're getting the wrong output.

Comment: I'm sorry. I get no output with the inner select, and the wrong output with the version above.

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping on it, the logic came to me. The following seems to have solved all my problems.

```
$sqlInbox = "
    SELECT a.*
    FROM (SELECT * FROM messages
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS a
    WHERE receiver='$log_username' OR sender='$log_username' 
    GROUP BY parent
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
```